# 'Templating' over Python types

Tags: python, c++, metaprogramming

Coming from C++, I have a couple of Python types which I want to specialise depending on an enumeration. Rather than storing the enum value as a member on the Python types, I would prefer to 'template' the type over this flag. This would look something like:

```
template<typename T>
struct base {};

using weak = base<WEAK>;
using strong = base<STRONG>;
```

Is such a construct possible (or even recommended) in Python?

Edit:
So specifically what I'm trying to do is provide a base class which wraps another object. This base class will ensure the wrapped object contains certain attributes. The deriving classes store some additional members. Users will create objects using the derived types

Comment: I mean python is dynamically typed. The types are determined at runtime. That is possible because that is what python is about. Since everything is an object as well you can alter their properties at runtime...

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This looks like it could be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Please write down what are you trying to do. In general, python is more flexible than C++, therefore, you don't **need** to use templates - there is usually much simpler solution!